# Using node/express/passport, how can I make a user object available to the browser?

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, passport.js

This is a 'best practices' question. (UPDATED for clarity)

I am trying to find the best way to make my browser-side code adaptive to user attributes, like whether the user is authenticated, an admin, or has certain attributes.

I am creating a static application.  For some valid reasons, I cannot have the pages rendered by the server.  They need to be static; the same pages are served to everyone; so a solution where the server renders pages isn't feasible (please take that as given for the sake of this question).

All of the security of this application is server-side.  All served pages and routes are access-managed by express and passport, verifying authentication from the cookie sent by the browser, and redirecting to /login when authentication fails.  So this isn't about moving security to the browser side; I very much am implementing security server-side;  this is about how to present state to the user.

I am using express-session to store the session id in a cookie.  By default, it only puts the session id in the cookie, and marks it httpOnly, so I can't access it from browser code.

I modified the config of express-session to turn off httpOnly, so I can now see the cookie on the browser via javascript, but it is still just the session id.

What I'd like to be able to do is attach additional, specific information to the session cookie so my pages can decide what to show/hide based on this information.

So the question comes down to:

How do I get express/passport to pass a session cookie with additional, specific user attributes, and how do I read it on the client?

Comment: The cookie contains what you "return" in `passport.serializeUser()`, which usually is the user id but it doesn't have to be.

Comment: Odd.  I am returning the username in serializeUser (I'm using passport-local-mongoose which is implementing this for me) but I'm only seeing an obscure session id in the client.  There must be something downstream of this that is modifying the session info...

Comment: Yeah sorry, `serializeUser` only determines what is stored in the _session_, not in the session _cookie_. That's what `express-session` does, and AFAIK it doesn't really have a way to override what's being stored in that cookie. But that said, you can always set your own cookie with the relevant data.

Comment: Ah, I see.  I guess what I'm looking for is a way to add additional attributes to the cookie that is returned.  I suppose if I knew how to do that I'd not have needed to ask the question.  What's the best practice with these frameworks for adjusting the cookies?

Comment: I don't think you can control what `express-session` writes to the cookie, but like I said, you can set an _additional_ cookie (using [`res.cookie()`](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#res.cookie)) that contains whatever you want. Alternatively (and probably more safe) is to have an endpoint that returns the data you require in your pages, and use an AJAX/fetch call to retrieve that data from the frontend.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that you are using passport for authentication so that will be the starting point of my proposed solution.

Remember we invoke done(err) if an exception occurs while trying to connect to our database, otherwise if the user is not found or the passwords do not match, we invoke done(null, false). If successful we invoke done(null, user). This attaches the user object to the request object of express (**req.user**).

Now that we have that out of the way, this is how we can make the user object attributes available to the user:

```
app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.render('index', {
        // Ternary operator which checks if the user object is empty or not
        username: req.user ? req.user.username: '',
        title: 'Tutorial'
    })
);
```

I then display the 'username', if a user is logged in the username will not be empty otherwise I display the form:

```
<%if( !username ) {%>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/signup">Signup</a></li>
            <li><a href="/signin">Signin</a></li>
        </ul>
    <%} else {%>
        <a href="#"><p><%= username %></p></a>

        <form method="post" action="/posts">
            <input type="text" name="title"><br/>
            <textarea name="content"></textarea><br/>
            <input type="submit" value="Post">
        </form>
    <%}%>
```

You could do the same with an attribute like 'role' for your users and check if the role is an admin or not in your view file. I am not quite sure if this answers your question though, hope it helps.

Comment: I wasn't entirely clear; I want to do this purely client-side, without dynamic server-generated pages.

Comment: @JimBaldwin My bad, maybe you could provide more info in the question to clarify it as you said, I personally can't wrap the solution in my head. Best of luck

Comment: Updated question.  I think this is more about building a custom session token with express, or more about me figuring out which search keywords I'm not using to find the answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

@robertklep's suggestion ended up being what I implemented.

Since express-session intentionally places only a session id it the session cookie, and that appears to be unchangeable, my only route to do this was to place an additional cookie in the response using res.cookie(), and I read that in my client app wherever needed.